# if statement bug in php and html

Tags: php, html

```
<img id="post_like_btn_<?php echo $post_info['id']; ?>" class="post_like_btn" 
<?php $like_result = data_like($dbc, $user_info['id']);
  while($like_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($like_result)){ 
    if($post_info['id'] == $like_info['post_id'])
      { echo 'src="img/like/like_active.png"';
      }  else{echo 'src="img/like/like_dark.png"'}?>>
```

I have this code to change the icon image on the like button when the post id exists in likes table but when there are no values in the table, else statement does not work and shows no image. I tried to add '&& !== null' to if condition but it does not work either.

Comment: When if condition is false, you want to show the `else` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no data in the likes tables for the user, the `while` loop has nothing to iterate over. That means the `if` condition never actually gets executed.

It's also worth noting another issue: It looks like your `while` loop will iterate over all results for all posts. If your user has liked other posts (besides the one being displayed) then your `else` clause will be executed multiple times, giving you multiple `src` attributes in your `img` tag (most or all of them referring to `like_dark.png`).

Ideally, what you need to do is make your database query search only for the user's likes on the ID of the post being displayed. That way you won't need a `while` loop at all. You just need to check if any result was found. If so, output `like_active.png`, otherwise output `like_dark.png`.

If you're not able to modify the query for some reason (or if you want to avoid multiple queries when displaying several posts on a page), your loop will need to go through each record and just set a boolean variable to `true` if it sees a like matching the current post ID. *After* the `while` loop, check that boolean variable in an `if` condition and only output the `src` attribute then. That way, you'll only output one `src` attribute, no matter how many records you've iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

missing closing bracket on the while loop:

```
while($like_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($like_result)){ 
  if($post_info['id'] == $like_info['post_id'])
      { echo ' src="img/like/like_active.png"';}
  else{echo ' src="img/like/like_dark.png"';}
}?>>
```

also since the following is common:
src="img/like/like"

you could remove that out of the if statement and just switch between the active and dark.png states.

Comment: nothing happened when i add the missing bracket i think it has something to do with the condition because it works just fine when there is information in the array but when the like table is empty and there is nothing to compare with it returns nothing